# Encrypt username

Tags: 7

How do I go about encrypting "username" so that it is not saved in plain text format in database. I was looking for a module that does this, but couldn't find one.

Would adding logic (`hook_user_presave()` and `hook_user_load()`) as described in [How can you encrypt the username and email address in the database, to protect against emails being stolen from a compromised database (D7)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25028/how-can-you-encrypt-the-username-and-email-address-in-the-database-to-protect-a) be sufficient? The accepted answer says:

> This is just my point of view, but if you want do it what you can use this module http://drupal.org/project/aes and with some user hooks, such as `hook_user_presave()` and `hook_user_load()`.

Comment: I was poking around in user.module yesterday, and saw a bunch of queries that relied on username (eg, `user_is_blocked`).  This may be baked in pretty deep.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be easier to store an arbitrary string or number (maybe the UID) as the username, and then store the actual (encrypted) username in a custom field.

This would mean writing a custom login script that uses your custom table, however it means you won't have to start changing stuff in the users module.